# Insert objects inside a function in a loop

Tags: r, merge

I have a list of object named `listed`. Each one has different data that I want to merge into one object called `result`, created before. I created a loop where I would like to merge all the data. But when I want to put the object inside the function it doesn't work

```
for (l in 1:length(listed)){
       result <- merge(result, listed[[l]], by.x="GOterm", by.y="GO.ID", all=TRUE) 
    }
```

While if I used instead of the the object inside

> > listed[[l]]
>
> data

```
result <- merge(result, data, by.x="GOterm", by.y="GO.ID", all=TRUE)
```

It works well.

How can I insert a valid object name for the merge function?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Your code is not correctly formatted. And, what is the error message if it doesn't work ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format it properly, my error message is: `Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that some of the items in `listed` do not have a `GO.ID` column. You can find which ones by doing:

```
which(!mapply(`%in%`, list("GO.ID"), lapply(listed, names)))
```

Fix your data and your `for` loop should work as you intended.

---

Here is an example:

```
listed <- list(data.frame(GO.ID  = 1:3, v2 = 4:6),
               data.frame(GO.ID  = 1:3, v2 = 4:6),
               data.frame(GO.id  = 1:3, v2 = 4:6))

which(!mapply(`%in%`, list("GO.ID"), lapply(listed, names)))
# [1] 3
```

---

**EDIT:** Following the comments below, it appears `listed` is a list of variables names, e.g. `listed <- list("data", "data2", "data3")`. So the answer should be:

```
for (l in 1:length(listed)) {
    result <- merge(result, get(listed[[l]]), by.x="GOterm", by.y="GO.ID", all=TRUE) 
}
```

or nicer:

```
for (df in mget(unlist(listed))) {
    result <- merge(result, df, by.x="GOterm", by.y="GO.ID", all=TRUE) 
}
```

Comment: I think I have not expressed well, the data is inside listed, and the only  item inside and it have a GO.ID column. Therefore when I apply your line I get this
`which(!mapply(`%in%`, list("GO.ID"), lapply(listed, names)))
[1] 1` 
and when I do  `names(data)` I get `[1] "GO.ID"      "Sort"       "Compressed"`. So it is inside

Comment: Well, this is telling you that the first item inside `listed` does not look like `data`. It is missing a `GO.ID` column. You can do `names(listed[[1]]` and you will see it... If this is still not answering your problem, please provide the output of `str(listed)`, you could paste it at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Of course, because it reads just a character not an object. 
`names(listed[[1]]) NULL` That's why I asked if there is a way to insert there an object from a list of objects

Comment: We don't know what `listed` looks like and how it relates to `data`. For your current code to work, `listed` should look like `list(data, data, data)` but apparently it is not the case. I cannot help more unless you give more info, that's why I ask that you please provide `str(listed)`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot: `str(listed) chr "data"`, thanks for all the help.

Comment: Suddenly it is a totally different problem... You just need to do: `result <- merge(result, get(listed), by.x="GOterm", by.y="GO.ID", all=TRUE)`. And no need for a `for` loop if there is a single object name in `listed`.

Comment: THANKS, I didn't realize to use the get function. 
In this case, the loop is not needed, but this was just an example and  I didn't realize it was not relevant for the question